# BTRFS folder suddenly shows up as a file

Tags: linux, btrfs, corruption

So, I have a BTRFS drive and a folder that contains videos from my capture card moved to a folder on the drive. I was trying to check what videos were in the folder and went to `cd` into it, but instead got this error.

```
bash: cd: /nasa/Media/MovedFromRazer: Not a directory
```

Running `stat /nasa/Media/MovedFromRazer` returns this:

```
`  File: /nasa/Media/MovedFromRazer
  Size: 61211095724 Blocks: 119552928  IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 32h/50d Inode: 438971540   Links: 1
Access: (0755/-rwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2023-06-02 19:40:31.172407100 -0400
Modify: 2023-06-02 19:37:29.540651200 -0400
Change: 2023-06-03 11:13:55.296383034 -0400
 Birth: 2023-06-03 11:04:17.358315235 -0400`
```

Additionally, running `file /nasa/Media/MovedFromRazer` returns this:

```
/nasa/Media/MovedFromRazer: ISO Media, MP4 v2 [ISO 14496-14]
```

I should also mention that the drive was originally EXT4 but converted to BTRFS, and the folder was created sometime after the conversion.

Any way to fix this?

Comment: Is it possible that rather than moving videos into _subdirectory_ `/nasa/Media/MovedFromRazer`, you instead overwrote the _file_ `/nasa/Media/MovedFromRazer` with each video?